# How does libusb detect an USB device via hotplug under Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, libusb, hotplugging

For research i looked into Libusb to see how hotluging is done. For Linux, i found the corresponding source in **libusb\os\linux_udev.c** where a thread is started which makes a poll() on udev. However, after spending hours in the sources of Libusb I can't figure out how hotpluging in Windows is done.

In **libusb\os\windows_winusb.c** obviously the winusb driver is used to get a device list (**static int winusb_get_device_list(..)**) but this is not necearilly a hotplug thing. Can someone point me int the right direction?

I use usb4java (a libusb Java wrapper) in my project and can detect an attach/detach event just fine, but I want to know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jan 28, 2024, `libusb` does not support hotplug on Windows. That is why you can't find it in the source code. There is a [bug open](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/86) to add the feature since 2015 and it looks like it may get implemented [soon](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/pull/1406).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this. I found out that according to the libusb dev-forum, it can't. In my case this was done by the java4usb wrapper, which is hotplug-able because of the JavaX API javax.usb.